# How to dismiss an Alert component programmatically after a period of time

Tags: javascript, android, ios, react-native

Here is my code

```
onCreate() {

    const insert = {
        title: this.state.title,
        body: this.state.body,
    };

    Meteor.call('documents.upsert', insert, (err, response) => {
        if (err) {
            this.setState({ error: err.reason});
        } else {
            Alert.alert('SUCCESS', 'Document inserted successfuly !');
            this.setState({
                title: '',
                body: '',
                error: '',
            });
            this.props.navigation.navigate('DocumentsList');
        }
    });
}
```

I want to display Alert for few seconds before closing it and navigate to another page

I want solution for Alert component, not Modal.

Thanks